# oj-bind-text and oj-bind-if return the same value even if I use not operator

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

Currently I have a web app using Oracle Jet and knockout js, I am using oj-bind-if to show some html code but I have noticed that the following sentence:

```
<oj-bind-text value="[[presenter.isValid]]"></oj-bind-text>
<oj-bind-text value="[[!presenter.isValid]]"></oj-bind-text>
```

Always return the same value, presenter.isValid is a boolean but I am doing a ! (NOT) in my oj-bind-text even in oj-bind-if the behavior is the same.
Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Observable element, try using -

```
presenter.isValid()
```